# Visual Studio pre-publish script

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there the possibility to run a script (a batch file) before and after a Publish operation?

It would be very useful to copy a app_offline.htm file in the project folder to "stop" IIS and let the publishing/copying happen without access denied, and when finish to delete the file.  (btw I use Publish with Output to FOLDER on my webserver, so no Azure pipelines or Github actions are used).

I'm aware of the existence of pre and post build script, but obviously I don't want to run every time I build.

I'm using now VS 2022 Professional.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 .
I also want to run a batch file before and after a Publish.
Finaly,I find the answer on Microsoft.

url : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Title : Run a target before or after publishing